# Inclusão de um novo campo no subdocument do Typegoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, collection

Como faço para incluir um campo a mais no subdocument da classe User?

```js
class Car {
  @prop()
  public model?: string;
}

class User {
  @prop()
  public name?: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public age!: number; 

  @prop({ ref: () => Car })
  public cars?: Ref<Car>[]; 
}
```

Coleção Car populada:

```js
Car A
{
  "_id": "1"
  "model": "Ferrari"
}

Car B
{
  "_id": "2"
  "model": "Tesla"
}
```

Coleção User populada de acordo com a classe padrão:

```js
User
{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "Jonh Doe",
  "age": 25,
  "cars": [
    { "_id": "1" },
    { "_id": "2" }
  ]
}
```

Preciso incluir um campo "status" na array cars da coleção User, conforme abaixo:

```js
User
{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "Jonh Doe",
  "age": 25,
  "cars": [
    { "_id": "1", "status": false },
    { "_id": "2", "status": true }
  ]
}
```

Comment: O que seria esse `status`? Pelo que demonstrou na pergunta, por que nao adicionar como uma `prop` da classe `Car`?

Comment: status seria para saber se o usuário está com aquele carro ou não. Essa é uma propriedade específica do usuário, por isso não dá para colocar na prop da classe Car.